# Lightbox rel gallery

Tags: lightbox

Lightbox gallery style, I have four pictures shown on one page, if I move forward to next page I see next four pictures, and so on. Is it possible to add to lightbox gallery (rel attrib) pictures which are on this page and all further pages?

PHP/HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

This is what you're looking for?

Comment: I am already using it, Omg it is so simple i just don't add img src :)

Comment: Yes it is, look in their documentation, you can do even a lot more :)